# Mysql stop at first desired WHERE

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Lets say i have this statement:

`select * from t1 
join t2 on t1.id = t2.user_id 
where A 
OR B 
OR C ;`

this query will perform all where conditions and return all of them results at once. i just want to get the result of **first** `where` clause that has a result  and the order of where clauses is **important**. how should i rewrite this query to get desired result?

Comment: The order of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause is *not* important.  In fact, there is no guarantee that they are applied in any particular order.

Comment: in MS SQL, i would use " TOP 1"  (so: SELECT TOP 1 * .....), in MySQL, you can use Limit 1 (at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from t1 
join t2 on t1.id = t2.user_id 
where
CASE    WHEN EXISTS(select * from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.user_id where A)
            THEN A
        WHEN EXISTS(select * from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.user_id where B)
            THEN B
        WHEN EXISTS(select * from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.user_id where C)
            THEN C
        ELSE FALSE
END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order the results, then use `order by`:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.user_id 
where A OR B OR C
order by (case when A then 1 when B then 2 when C then 3 end);
```

If you want one row, then add `limit 1` to this query:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.user_id 
where A OR B OR C
order by (case when A then 1 when B then 2 when C then 3 end)
limit 1;
```

If you want more than one row, then I would count the number of matching rows for each condition, and use that information in the `where`:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.user_id cross join
     (select sum(A) as num_A, sum(B) as num_B, sum(C) as num_C
      from t1 join
           t2
           on t1.id = t2.user_id 
     ) tt
where A or
      (num_A = 0 and B) or
      (num_A = 0 and num_B = 0 and C);
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote?  This is seems like a possible interpretation of the question.

Comment: thanks.if i want to preserve the order of conditional in `where` clause, what should i do?

Comment: Are you looking for one row or more than one row?

Comment: just one row. @Dylan solution do the job but its messy and blow up the query  a bit .